# Using ViewBag in Layout page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have my `_Layout.cshtml` file that uses the `ViewBag` model to render some dynamic content.

I understand `ViewBag` can be populated in the controller and accessed in the view and/or layout page.

My question is, if my Layout page is using `@ViewBag.SiteName`, I want to avoid having to set this variable in each controller before I return the view. Is there a way to set this variable on a global level?  Or how else should I pass this data to the layout page?

Comment: Please see if this helps! http://forums.asp.net/t/1820819.aspx?Global+ViewBag+Property

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453327/how-to-set-viewbag-properties-for-all-views-without-using-a-base-class-for-contr

Comment: You could create an action filter that sets the property, then apply the filter globally in `global.asax `

Comment: I tried setting the `ViewBag.SiteName` in global.asax and it didn't work.

Comment: You could do this as a child action `@{Html.Action("SiteName", "Home");}` then have a `[ChildActionOnly]` action that returns a string.

Comment: @ControlFreak, you may have misunderstood my comment. You set the property in a custom action filter then apply the filter to all controllers in `Application_Start()` of global.asax

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you set anything in ViewBag - this happens **after** the Layout has been rendered -
You've missed the boat.

As others have mentioned, you can create a "helper" controller:

```
public class LayoutController : BaseController
{
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult SiteName()
    {
        return new ContentResult {Content = "Site name goes here"};
    }
}
```

Then, in your layout:

```
@{Html.Action("SiteName", "Layout")}
```

Comment: I call something like @{Html.Action("SiteName", "Layout")} in javascript and result is empty string. Example. var a=''@{Html.Action("SiteName", "Layout")}" , and a is empty string. When debugging method return string corretly but is empty inside view.

Comment: I know.It should be RenderAction in my case  :)