# How to pass data using ViewBag to _Layout.cshtml to show next to menu ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I need to pass List to _LayOut.Cshml in ASP.NET MVC. Let us say, I want to show city dropdown next to Login. It will be there for all views.

I know few options like  creating a base controller class , Action filter

But can not getting it work. Any help ?

Comment: Can you show us your piece of code ?

Comment: I don't have a code to show. let us say I will set viewbag.city = List<City>. I want this viewbag to be present fro _layout.cshtml. Also I dont want to set it in all controllers.

Comment: Check these questions:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26224790/using-viewbag-in-layout-page

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20204424/asp-net-mvc5-access-viewbag-from-layout

Answer (score 0):

You should use a ViewComponent to perform this functionality.  The view component can load the list from your data source and then bind to a strongly typed model in the view component's Default.cshtml.

Then in your _Layout.cshtml file you simply call the ViewComponent like such:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("CityList", new { state= "MA" })
```

You can read more about View Components here:
http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2016/01/02/goodbye-child-actions-hello-view-components.aspx