# ASP.NET 5 (vNext) - Using Filters

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET MVC app that I am trying to migrate to MVC 6 (ASP.NET 5). With that in mind, I have some filters that were added using the process described in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453327/how-to-set-viewbag-properties-for-all-views-without-using-a-base-class-for-contr). However, with Global.asax being replaced with Startup.cs, I'm not sure where to add my global filters anymore.

In addition, in my filter I have:

```
public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
{
  context.Controller.ViewBag.MyProperty = "[TESTING]";
}
```

When I run `dnx . run` now, I get an error that says:

```
MyFilter.cs(11,22): error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'ViewBag' and no extension method 'ViewBag' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

How do I add global filters in ASP.NET 5 (MVC 6)?

Comment: I haven't used vNext yet, but it sounds like controllers can be POCO objects. I have no idea how `ViewBag` works in that design, but I suspect that's where your problem is actually occurring. If it can be a POCO object, `context.Controller` has to be an `object`, which can't be guaranteed by the compiler to have the property you've listed. I'd suggest looking into how to register `ViewBag` elements, and potentially just even write a class specifically for what you want to register and DI it into each controller. But again, I haven't used any of this, I just know what I heard from //build/.

Answer (score 4):

To register global filter you can do following:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(new YourCustomFilter());
    });
}
```

in your Startup.cs

Regarding error you're getting, `context.Controller` has object type and therefore ViewBag property can't be resolved. Cast it to Controller type first:

```
public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
{
    var controller = (Controller) context.Controller;

    controller.ViewBag.MyProperty = "[TESTING]";
}
```