# Can we call interface method from razor view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have to call a method which is implemented in a class. Is it possible from razor view?

Note: I dont want to expose the class directly to view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can bind your Razor model to an interface (although you'll have to inject a concrete instance somewhere, typically your controller).

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IList<string> list = new List<string> {"one", "two"};
    return View(list);
}
```

Razor view:

```
@model IList<string>
@{ Model.RemoveAt(0); }
```

In this simple test case, `RemoveAt()` is guaranteed by the `IList<T>` interface, meaning that the underlying concrete implementation has not been exposed to the view.

An additional example would be a custom implementation where one public method of a concrete class is guaranteed by an interface and another is not:

```
public class Test : ITest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string GetName()
    {
        return Name;
    }

    public int GetId()
    {
        return Id;
    }
}

public interface ITest
{
    string GetName();
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var test = new Test() {Id = 1, Name = "Test"};
    return View(test);
}
```

Razor View:

```
@model ITest
@(Model.GetId())
```

In this case `GetId()` would be highlighted red in the Razor view as invalid syntax and you would receive the following compilation error at runtime.

> ITest' does not contain a definition for 'GetId'

On the flipside, `Model.GetName()` would correctly output "Test".

Comment: Is there a way that i can create an instance in global.asax instead of creating in controller? because am going to use the method in Layout.
Thanks!!

Comment: That's a good deal more complicated (and is honestly a separate question).  Your best bet is something like this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453327/how-to-set-viewbag-properties-for-all-views-without-using-a-base-class-for-contr