# Best way to modify MVC site to display that you're on a test site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is there a quick and easy way to detect which environment your app is running on and modify the html accordingly?

I would like to change my shared layout view to give the header a red background when it is running on my test server.

I'd like to avoid writing an IIS module or HTTP response filter if possible.

Comment: I don't really agree with the "how to detect that the site is running in debug" duplicate, as this will mean you can put a release build on your test server and not see any difference.

Comment: @CodeCaster yeah - good point > I didn't really want to deploy to the test site in debug mode

Comment: Can you do an URL check in the layout file and append a style sheet accordingly. Something like `Request.URL.Contains("debugurl")`

Comment: How come this was closed as dupe with only two votes. The second one being community?

Comment: Guess that must be it. Not sure why it wouldn't show your name then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a filter attribute that runs for every action method and set a property in every view's ViewBag, for example by reading the environment from the web.config. Where "it" being an appSettings key like "environment", or a list of hostname and color mappings.

See [How to set ViewBag properties for all Views without using a base class for Controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453327/how-to-set-viewbag-properties-for-all-views-without-using-a-base-class-for-contr) and especially [Mirak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21130867/266143).

Then in your layout, use this ViewBag property to set the HTML style or class.