# How do I assign a value to a WebViewPage property from a filter or a controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

After reading this question and its answer: [How to set ViewBag properties for all Views without using a base class for Controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453327/how-to-set-viewbag-properties-for-all-views-without-using-a-base-class-for-contr) I have created a custom WebViewPage with an extra property on it:

```
public abstract class MyWebViewPage<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel>
{
    protected MyObject MyProperty { get; set; }
}

public abstract class MyWebViewPage: MyWebViewPage<dynamic> { }
```

This has worked well, and the property is now accessible and correctly typed when I use it in any of my views.  But now I'd like to automatically assign a value to this property from an ActionFilter, how do I access the instance of "MyWebViewPage" from the filter in order to assign to that property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign your value into ViewData and get this data from the getter of your property.

```
namespace NorthWindMVC.Views
{
    public abstract class TestViewPage<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel>
    {
        protected string TestProperty
        {
            get { return ViewData["TestProperty"] != null ? ViewData["TestProperty"].ToString() : String.Empty; }
            set { ViewData["TestProperty"] = value; }
        }
    }

    public abstract class TestViewPage : TestViewPage<dynamic>
    {
    }
}
```

And in your filter,

```
namespace NorthWindMVC.Filters
{
    public class TestActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.Controller.ViewData["TestProperty"] = "mahmut";
        }
    }
}
```