# How to pass Data from Controller to layout using ActionFilterAttribute in Asp.Net Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

On my Website user is Authenticated based on three things on the login

- UserId
- RoleId
- SiteId

Now After checking All these and the user logs in, The problem is, For Example, If the User has an Admin role on site 1 and has a Normal role in site2 if at login he chooses site 2 which he has a Normal Role in. He is logged in as Admin. So I want to capture the role id on login and be able to use it in my layout view. I found this when I searched 'ActionFilterAttribute' which enable me to use a ViewBage everywhere. But Now how can I pass this logged in user role id to This 'ActionFilterAttribute' and Add it to ViewBag and be able to use it Everywhere on my website. I didn't find anything that can help me achieve this.

This is My login Action In AccountController

```
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.userName);
                var id = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(user.Id);
                var query = (from st in dbContext.UserRoles
                            where st.UserId == user.Id
                            select st.RoleId).ToList();

                
                if (user != null && AuthenticateAD(model.userName, model.Password))
                {
                    for (int i=0; i<query.Count;i++)
                    {
                        if (await applicationUserManager.IsInRoleByIdAsync(id, query[i], 
                             model.sites))
                        {
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) && Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
                            {
                                return Redirect(returnUrl);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                model.RoleId = query[i];
                                await signInManager.SignInAsync(user, false);
                                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", query[i]);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Not Authorized");
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
                }
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

This is My layout, I check if signed in user Is in role Admin. Now If I passed the role Id from Login I want to be able to use it here

```
    @if (signInManager.IsSignedIn(User) && User.IsInRole("Admin") )
     {
        Here it shows ManageUser option
     }
```

AuthenticateAD

```
      public bool AuthenticateAD(string username, string password)
        {
            using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, 
               "xxx.com"))
            {
                return context.ValidateCredentials(username, password);
            }
        }
```

If there is Any way I can Pass the role Id to layout it would be great. Thanks in Advance to Any One who Answers

The `ActionFilterAttribute` Code I Found is here [ActionFilterAttribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453327/how-to-set-viewbag-properties-for-all-views-without-using-a-base-class-for-contr/21130867#21130867) By @Mohammad Karimi

Comment: Can you share how are you logging in the user and initiate the user session in method `AuthenticateAD` ?

Comment: @Chetan It Authenticate user base on Active Directory using User Principle. I Will post it

Answer (score 0):

You can add a BaseController, then you should give inheritance to your other controllers the Base Controller. If you add OnActionExecuting to your BaseBontroller  every time if will works. Then you can pass the data with ViewBag to Layout.

BaseController

```
    public class BaseController : Controller
        {
            public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
            {
                ViewBag.Test = "Test";
            }
        }
```

HomeController

```
    public class HomeController : BaseController
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {          
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Layout

```
   @{ 
      var test = ViewBag.Test;
    }
```

Comment: Thank You for your Answer But how can I pass the Role Id I'm getting from login page to this baseController? .. If I understand this correctly I can set a ViewBag in BaseController and use it everywhere but the value of the viewBag I want it to come from Login Which is the roleId. You can check in my code it's in query[i]

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
BaseController

 public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        public int RoleId = 0;

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            //Read RoleId from cookie or session;
            ViewBag.Test = "";//set cooki value
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            ViewBag.Test = RoleId;
            //Set RoleId to cookie or session
        }
    }

HomeController

 public class HomeController : BaseController
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            RoleId = 15;
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the data from the login page and match the data with your database table. If the record matches with your table data then you will return the ID of the data and after that you can store it in Session. Session will allow you to get that ID wherever you want.
Like:

```cs
public IActionResult SignIn(User user)
 {
     
     var result = _productCRUD.SignInUser(user);
   
     User userData = _productCRUD.CheckSignInUser(user.Email, user.Password);
     if (result == true)
     {
         _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("UserId", 
          userData.Id);
         _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString("UserEmail", 
          userData.Email);
         _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString("UserName", 
          userData.FullName);
     }
     else if (result == false)
     {
         TempData["Message"] = "Email or Password doesn't match.";
         return RedirectToAction("SignUp", "Home");
     }

     // storing userData in the session.
     var UserID = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("UserId");
     Console.WriteLine("User ID is : " + UserID);

     return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
 }
```